# Video as launch screen in IOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, launch-screen

Video as  launch screen in IOS Objective C.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: simple, initialy create the thumbnail (add video thumb)and add into launch screen, after that loadvideo in anothercontoller (set video controller as ur inital controller)and navigate to anywhere

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik , Your Answer is not match my requirement, Below explaination of Mr.Abdu match nicely my requirement. Anyway thanks for your quick reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moorthy
 You can use AVPlayer and AVPlayerViewController help for Achieving this.

I will Explain you in detail the process of doing this trick.

**Step One**
Add following framework in your Xcode project and import them in on your Appdelegate.

1. @import AVFoundation;
2. @import AVKit;
3. @import UIKit;

**Step Two**
Add following piece of code in your Appdelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions Method

```
    // grab a local URL to our video
        NSURL *videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"myvideo" withExtension:@"mov"];

        // create an AVPlayer
        AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];

        // create a player view controller
        AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
        controller.player = player;
        controller.showsPlaybackControls = false;
        controller.view.frame = self.window.frame;
        controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
        self.window.rootViewController = controller;
        [player play];

// Adding Observer for your video file,
        NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [notificationCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoDidFinish:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:nil];
```

**Step Three**

After Video Completion you will be take into this place

```
- (void)videoDidFinish:(id)notification {   

AVPlayerItem *p = [notification object];
        //do something with player if you want

 //Remove Observer  
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];     

//your initial view can proceed from here 
[self ProccedToYourViewController];
}
```

**Some Tips**

You can smoothly stop your video play by adding fade in and fade out animation, I will show you how i did for myself

```
//AvplayerViewController View(Video View).
[self.controller.view setAlpha:1.0f];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{
//AvplayerViewController View(Video View) setting to hide.
            [self.controller.view setAlpha:0.0f];
//initialview(Your Initial View) that add as window root now
            self.window.rootViewController  = initialview;
            [initialview.view setAlpha:1.0f];
            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
} completion:nil];
```

> Now You are ready to go. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your quick response ....

Comment: You are welcome dear... :)